# 404 on shopify checkout payment api

Tags: node.js, shopify-app

Shopify checkout API does not allow to complete a checkout without a transaction. For the transaction, I am using Shopify [checkout payment](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/sales_channels/payment#index) API but on GET or POST request Shopify returns 404 error. Checkout payment URL looks like:
https://store.shopify.com/admin/checkouts/092b08d0598fd2a850e06ed9a6c92aee/payments.json

I don't know that is there anything that I have forgotten to configure on my partner Shopify dashboard.

Comment: There is no code here to work with, also that url is not 404, it is there..

Comment: Actually, I was trying it with the postman. On other APIs Shopify works but on checkout payment API it is sending 404.

Comment: According to Shopify documentation, the given URL is:
/admin/checkouts/#{token}/payments.json and an access token should exist in request header named as X-Shopify-Access-Token=".

Answer (score 0):

In order to use checkout API, you need to convert your app into sales channel.
Then you need to request for payment processing to process payment.

More info: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/guides/sales-channel-sdk/getting-started

Comment: The sales channel is not required, OneClickUpsell is also based on custom checkout but this app is not signed in the Sales Channel.